# How does <param> know the type when not explicitly set?

Tags: roslaunch, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently doing a C++ program which executes launchfiles and monitor their processes if they die
and I now I wonder how normally the type of the value of the param is selected.

Actually I thought it is saved as string all the time and then depending on what the user
decides to have it, trying to be converted.

But when I look at the functions in param.h ... this does not seem to be the case.
So how are they checked if they are bool, float, double, string, when no type is given?

Regards,

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216313/how-does-%3Cparam%3E-know-the-type-when-not-explicitly-set?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah ok found it myself,

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param

Specifies the type of the parameter. If you don't specify the type, roslaunch will attempt to automatically determine the type. These rules are very basic:

- numbers with '.'s are floating point,
- integers otherwise;
- "true" and "false" are boolean (not case-sensitive).
- all other values are strings

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1